# Fire click event only once

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a a `foreach` loop that displays some `db` entries.
In every entry i have a remove button that enables a `bootstrap's modal`.
I can cancel the remove process and hide the modal. The problem is that if i cancel and i proceed to remove another entry, the `click` event fires alongside with the previous clicks that have been canceled.

```
('.removeProperty').on('click',function(){

  var id = $(this).parents('.propertyIdSelect').attr('id');

  var $this= $(this);

  $this.parents('.propertyIdSelect').css('opacity','0.5'); 

  $('#confirmRemove').on('hidden.bs.modal', function() {
      $this.parents('.propertyIdSelect').css('opacity','1');
  });

  $('.removeButton').click(function(){
    removeProperty(id,$this);
  });

});
```

I want when the modal is hidden

```
$('#confirmRemove').on('hidden.bs.modal', function() {
    $this.parents('.propertyIdSelect').css('opacity','1');
});
```

to reset the click event.

**UPDATE:**

For some reason, where i need some explanation, i did the job by changing this

```
$('#confirmRemove').on('hidden.bs.modal', function() {
      $this.parents('.propertyIdSelect').css('opacity','1');
});
```

to this

```
$('#confirmRemove').unbind('click').on('hidden.bs.modal', function() {
          $this.parents('.propertyIdSelect').css('opacity','1');
 });
```

and this

```
 $('.removeButton').click(function(){
        removeProperty(id,$this);
  });
```

to this

```
$('.removeButton').unbind('click').click(function(){
    removeProperty(id,$this);
});
```

Comment: $('.removeProperty').off('click');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [**`one()`**](http://api.jquery.com/one/) instead of `on()` - when using `one()` the handler is automatically rebound first time it is triggered.

```
$('#confirmRemove').one('hidden.bs.modal', function() {
      $this.parents('.propertyIdSelect').css('opacity','1');
});
```